# how to render Multiple forms in one form in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a static page and static controller. In the page am using Jquery UI Accordion in a four category. Each category has separate controller, model and view. I am trying to render all the category into the accordion and work like it does separately. I got a problem with that, So, I tried to create a form in the static page and do like the following. But all the forms opened in the first tab. I want to open and save the form separately as per the tabs. Any idea would be more appreciated. Thanks

```
<div class="funding_form">
  <%= form_for(@funding_source, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Funding Source</legend>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :Source_name, 'Funding Source Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :Source_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <%= f.submit 'Save Source name', :class => 'funding_save', remote: true %> | <%= link_to 'Cancel', "#",  {:remote => true, :class => 'funding_cancel_button' } %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="packages_form">
  <%= form_for(@package, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Packages</legend>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :Package_name, 'Package Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :Package_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <%= f.submit 'Save Packages', :class => 'package_save', remote: true %> | <%= link_to 'Cancel', "#",  {:remote => true, :class => 'package_cancel_button' } %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put an ajax request on the click action of the tab, to call an action in the controller. I.e. have a method in your @package controller which when called, will render the partial packages form. You can then call this with an ajax request :)

For example, in your controller you may want to render the partial "form" you can have a controller method like such:

```
def return_data
 @package = Package.find(params[:id])

 render partial "form"
end
```

and you could call it using an ajax request such as:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: '/your_path/return_data',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data)
  });
```

you could then display it, perhaps assign the partial to a div and overwrite it every time you make an ajax request so one only ever displays :)

Comment: Thanks. I did in some other way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Learner Can you post answer?